# Swing Form Editor

Tags: java, .net, swing, layout

I'm a .net developer and I am studying Swing for Java and I have a question.

Is there any way to build the form controls by dragging and drop like a simple .net windows application project or WPF project?

I am using eclipse and it seems that everybody works with controls by adding positioning and width, height by code, I find that a pain in the a**.

Comment: Note that GUI designers tend to produce horrid, unresizable, non-PLAFable GUIs unless you understand the underlying layouts.  Whereas .net works on one OS (where you can get away with that), Java is designed to work on a number of different OS' (where you can't).

Comment: what? Swing addresses especially that problematic by providing a standard OS independent set of UI controls. And .Net does produce "horrid, unresizable, non-PLAFable GUIs" too, just like most designers, because most are not smart enough (yet) to generate neatly organize code. Although I have to say that WindowBuilder does produce code that is somewhat similar to what code I would write myself (and that I can edit), which is far less than what I can say about .Net :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Take a look at [Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) for Eclipse (install it from the [update site](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php)). [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) has also a built-in editor, if you prefer that IDE.

Comment: cool, Is Windows Builder largely used for Swing development community? I would like to  work on something that java community already heavily use tks

Comment: I cannot speak for everyone, but I can say that the plugin is the best out there, from all the ones that I tried. It's a comprehensive tool, meaning that it does not behave like .Net where you don't have access (or very little access) to the generated code. The tool actually lets you write and modify the components declarations almost without restrictions; it's smart enough to interpret the code and help you in a smart way. Even Netbeans does not do this. I strongly encourage you to try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a plugin to do that.

In Eclipse you can try [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).
[image]

In [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) this ability comes within the standard package.

Answer (score 2):

Java's Swing framework tries to address a broad set of platforms, and it does this by separating out look-and-feel concerns, layout concerns, etc. The most painful part of setting up a form is the layout, and that is driven by the LayoutManagers.

There are various LayoutManager implementations built to be used in conjunction with form designer tooling. I've personally had good results with IntelliJ's designer. See some [screen shots and feature listings here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would personally not recommend using any Drag and Drop builders. In some IDEs the generated code is not editable. Some IDEs allow you to edit the code, but the bottom line is no matter what IDE you use the generated code is very difficult to maintain. After a while you will find it difficult to work with it yourself.

Instead, since you are just starting out, I would recommend using a good layout manager right away. While we are on that, give the jdk's layout managers a wide berth. They are horrible and that's what causes most people to go in for the drag and drop solution. Instead try the Jgoodies Form Layout. Its very easy to understand and use. The link is here:

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/formsdemo/index.html

After you have understood that, try to give this builder I wrote a shot. It makes life even more simple:

http://code.google.com/p/swingobjects/source/browse/SwingObjects/src/org/aesthete/swingobjects/view/SwingObjFormBuilder.java